# Connecting to Django shell on Azure Websites

Tags: django, azure

On Heroku, I can connect to a Django shell by running

```
heroku run python manage.py shell
```

Is there an equivalent on Azure Websites?

Answer (score 0):

Aha! I realized I can just connect to the database by adding it as an additional database on my local version of the app.

Not exactly what I was thinking of originally, but it seems to solve all of my use cases, for example:

```
 python manage.py syncdb --database=live
```